# Problem with fixed menu - it covers content

Tags: html, css

I have problem with fixed menu :

```
header nav.nav__menu--desktop {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    background: #313639;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I used anchors in menu to id sections :

```
<nav class="nav__menu--desktop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutUs">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ourServices">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And when I click on option menu - for example service I have this result:

[image]

My nav covers content [height nav] :[image]

Comment: Post complete snippet please.

Comment: do you use javascript for scrolling down to the anchor tags?, if yes. calculate the header height and apply `margin-top: -headerheight` to the function

Comment: yes, I use js, my script : https://pastebin.com/NeTj3fnP

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limp here - as you did not provide a fully reproducible example -, I think the problem is that your header is [fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), but you did not deduct it's height from the container which covers the content.

Giving an Element `position: fixed` will take it out of the *flow* of the page and treat it like it is not there. In order for your page to work as intended, you should give the content this style: `height: calc(100% - 60px);`. The *60px* are the height of the fixed header. I tried to recreate your problem in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111) for you to try out this solution.

Answer (score 0):

My JS + css

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("main_nav");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

```css
header nav.nav__menu--desktop {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    background: #313639;
    z-index: 999;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved problem in very simple way - I added in css in my sections:

```
    scroll-margin-top: 60px;
```

And work :)